# Instruction count in region of interest

Tags: riscv

I have an application source that needs to be compiled and run for RISC-V ISA. I have multiple regions of interest in my applications source code. I would like to find the number of integer, floating point and memory instructions executed in each region of interest.

I tried spike ISA simulator. But this only provides the entire dynamic execution trace. I would rather like to insert the instrumentation point for dumping the statistics from my source code.

Is there any way to obtain this information?

Any help really appreciated!